# foundation scss file not getting imported in App.scss file in my react project

Tags: css, reactjs, npm, sass, zurb-foundation

I installed zurb-foundation using npm and tries to import the .scss of the former to my App.scss file. I'm using the "live sass server" for the compilation of the .scss code to .css code. While the .css file gets created but it shows no code even though I imported the .scss from foundation to my App.scss

[pic shows the .scss code on the left and corresponding .css code on the right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/euCzT.png)

Comment: You have to add file with import not directory.

Comment: I didn't understand. Please elaborate a little, I'm a total noob. As far as I understand you must be suggesting me to add @import "file location"; in my App.scss. I already did it, please see the pic.

Comment: You have to actually import / include single files. You can not import / include a whole directory / folder. See https://github.com/foundation/foundation-zurb-template/blob/master/src/assets/scss/app.scss for a working setup.

Answer (score 0):

if you have three file:

**SASS SYNTAX**

first file:

```
SASS SYNTAX
// foundation/_code.sass
code
  padding: .25em
  line-height: 0
```

second file:

```
// foundation/_lists.sass
ul, ol
  text-align: left

  & &
    padding:
      bottom: 0
      left: 0
```

you can add your files with import like this.

**note**: the name of file have to have this syntax:

`_{name of file}.sass`

```
// app.sass
@import foundation/code, foundation/lists
```

**SCSS SYNTAX**

first file:

```
// foundation/_code.scss
code {
  padding: .25em;
  line-height: 0;
}
```

second file:

```
// foundation/_lists.scss
ul, ol {
  text-align: left;

  & & {
    padding: {
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
    }
  }
}
```

third file:

```
// style.scss
@import 'foundation/code', 'foundation/lists';
```

for more info study: [sass docs @import](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/import)

Answer (score 0):

have you also tried `@import '../node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/foundation.scss'`?

But maybe you could just pick what you really need to use, for instance the breakpoint mixins for your scss, like:

```
@import "~foundation-sites/scss/util/util";
@import "~foundation-sites/scss/util/breakpoint";
```

otherwise the whole foundation code will be compiled to your css file, maybe you don't need everything.

You can also have a look at https://get.foundation/sites/docs/sass.html